# How to add a new line of text to an existing file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-processing

I would like to append a new line to an existing file without erasing the current information of that file. In short, here is the methodology that I am using the current time:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

Writer output;
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(my_file_name));  //clears file every time
output.append("New Line!");
output.close();
```

The problem with the above lines is simply they are erasing all the contents of my existing file then adding the new line text.

I want to append some text at the end of the contents of a file without erasing or replacing anything.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

you have to open the file in append mode, which can be achieved by using the `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)` constructor.

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(my_file_name, true));
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks so much! Please is there a way to append ("\n") at the end after each output? As you know it is appending everything in one line ignoring my "\n" escapes!

Comment: `BufferedWriter` has a `newLine()` method. You can use that, or use a `PrintWriter` instead, which provides a `println()` method

Comment: Thanks! but for some bizarre reason when I am trying to use the: 
output.newLine() | does not exist within the list of methods. I am using NetBeans 6.9. All the other methods exist there. Do you know what might be the cause of that?

Comment: yes, you are storing your `output` as a `Writer`, which is a smaller interface. You will have to explicitly store it as a `BufferedWriter output` if you want access to that method.

Comment: BufferedWriter does not do any magic implicitly. You need to invoke newLine() method then only it does. See the complete code here. 

 try(FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("/home/xxxx/playground/coivd_report_02-05-2021.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter bw= new BufferedWriter( fw)){
            bw.newLine();
            bw.append("When this COVID ends");

        }catch (IOException exception){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }

Answer (score 31):

The solution with `FileWriter` is working, however you have no possibility to specify output encoding then, in which case the default encoding for machine will be used, and this is usually not UTF-8!

So at best use `FileOutputStream`:

```
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(file, true), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Don't forget to close `FileOutputStream`

Comment: This solution solve problem for append exist utf-8 file.

Answer (score 20):

Starting from **Java 7**:

Define a path and the String containing the line separator at the beginning:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\first.last\\test.txt");
String s = System.lineSeparator() + "New Line!";
```

and then you can use one of the following approaches:

1. Using [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) (small files):

   ```
   try {
       Files.write(p, s.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   ```
2. Using [`Files.newBufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)(text files):

   ```
   try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(p, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
       writer.write(s);
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
       System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", ioe);
   }
   ```
3. Using [`Files.newOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) (interoperable with `java.io` APIs):

   ```
   try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(p, StandardOpenOption.APPEND))) {
       out.write(s.getBytes());
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   ```
4. Using [`Files.newByteChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) (random access files):

   ```
   try (SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(p, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
       sbc.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes()));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   ```
5. Using [`FileChannel.open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) (random access files):

   ```
   try (FileChannel sbc = FileChannel.open(p, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
       sbc.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(s.getBytes()));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   ```

Details about these methods can be found in the [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

Answer (score 14):

Try: "**\r\n**"

**Java 7 example:**

```
// append = true
try(PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt",true))) 
{
    output.printf("%s\r\n", "NEWLINE");
} 
catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: \r\n is for windows. It's better use "line.separator" property

Answer (score 9):

In case you are looking for a cut and paste method that creates and writes to a file, here's one I wrote that just takes a String input. Remove 'true' from PrintWriter if you want to overwrite the file each time.

```
private static final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

private synchronized void writeToFile(String msg)  {
    String fileName = "c:\\TEMP\\runOutput.txt";
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName, true));
        printWriter.write(newLine + msg);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (printWriter != null) {
            printWriter.flush();
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

On line 2 change `new FileWriter(my_file_name)` to `new FileWriter(my_file_name, true)` so you're appending to the file rather than overwriting.

```
File f = new File("/path/of/the/file");
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
            bw.append(line);
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)` constructor if you want to append data to file.

Change your code to this:

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(my_file_name, true));
```

From FileWriter javadoc:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a
>   file name. If the second argument is
>   *true*, then bytes will be written to
>   the end of the file rather than the
>   beginning.