# How can I save information in an existing textfile in Java?

Tags: java, file, text, load, save

I want to save information in a textfile I already created.  At school we only learnt to create a new one and save information in it.

How can I acheive this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4614244/760489

Answer (score 1):

By default, if you create a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter`, it will just overwrite the existing text file - so if that's what you want to do, you're fine already.

If you want to *append* to a file, use the overload of the constructors for either of those types which takes a `boolean` parameter to indicate append/overwrite:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("data.txt", true);
```

If you *have* been using `FileWriter`, by the way, I'd advise you to stop doing so - instead use `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`. This allows you to specify the encoding you want to use, instead of always using the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter fw = FileWriter(new File(pathToFile), true);  
fw.write(stringToWrite);
```