# Implement simple text editor

Tags: java, file, file-io

All I am trying is to implement a simple text-editor. I will keep this simple for now.
I have a `text-area` and `string variable` to hold the text and a file to write the contents of the `text-area`. Intuitively, I think there is a better way (better readability/agile code) to do the same below and this should work for notepad  :

```
 FileWriter out = new FileWriter("filename.txt");
 String sh = jTextArea1.getText();

 for (int i=0; i<sh.length(); i++)
 {
     if (sh.charAt(i) ==  '\n')
          out.write("\r\n");
     else
         out.write(sh.charAt(i));
  }
  out.close();
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: the for loop is somewhat turning me off i m looking for one-liner.... it works for other editors..like wordpad,etc,,but the notepad is skipping out the new line characters if i dont use "\r\n"

Comment: [OT]
also go thro' [1] gr8 tutorial
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/49721-simple-text-editor/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614227/how-to-add-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Use a JTextPane instead of a JTextArea. You need a `Document` object also. There way there's much more versatility also. Then You can use a one liner to write the entire document to a file

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

textPane.getEditorKit().write(bw, doc, 0, doc.getLength());   <-- one line
```

javadoc

```
public abstract void write(OutputStream out,
         Document doc,
         int pos,
         int len)
                    throws IOException,
                           BadLocationException
```

> Writes content from a document to the given stream in a format appropriate for this kind of content handler.

```
Parameters:
    out - The stream to write to
    doc - The source for the write.
    pos - The location in the document to fetch the content from >= 0.
    len - The amount to write out >= 0.
```

[JTextPane javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) | [EditorKit javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream,%20javax.swing.text.Document,%20int,%20int%29) | [Text Components Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) <-- I really recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh.replace("\n", "\r\n");
out.write(sh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `read(...)` and `write(...)` methods of a JTextComponent:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader( ... );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
edit.read( br, null );

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( ... );
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( writer );
edit.write( bw );
```