# BufferedWriter writes over existing file

Tags: java, file, text, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to create a program which saves text on a file and then text can be added onto the file. However, every time i try to write to the file, it overwrites it and doesn't write anything. I need it to add whatever information i want it UNDER the rest.

```
    FileReader input;
    BufferedReader readFile;

    FileWriter output;
    BufferedWriter writeFile;

    try {
    //  input = new FileReader(password_file);
        //readFile = new BufferedReader(input);

        output = new FileWriter(password_file);
        writeFile = new BufferedWriter(output);


        //while ((temp_user= readFile.readLine()) !=null) {
            //temp_pass = readFile.readLine();
        //}

        temp_user = save_prompt.getText();

        temp_pass = final_password;

                                        //Writes to the file
        writeFile.write(temp_user);
        writeFile.newLine();
        writeFile.write(temp_pass);

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use the other FileWriter constructor, the one that takes a boolean second parameter. The API should be able to help you. 2) You need to work on your Google search skills a bit.

Comment: See [`FileWriter(File,append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) & [`FileWriter(String,append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"You need to work on your Google search skills a bit."*  I have a theory that the OP's search was thwarted because they used 'override' instead of 'overwrite'.  But that is just a theory.  Don't expect me to explain the (now 5) answers that rushed headlong into answering this without searching.  My best guess would be 'vote-slutting'.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: nah. Just do a Google search using his very own question topic and it brings many results all with the correct answer. The first hit is to another one of many [similar stackoverflow questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614227/how-to-add-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java). This same question has been asked and answered a kagillion times, and one more of the same question on this site will not help anyone in the future. I stand by my recommendation that he work a bit more on his Google skills.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Couldn't hurt..  :)

Answer (score 15):

What you seek for is **Append** mode.

```
new FileWriter(file,true); // true = append, false = overwrite
```

Answer (score 8):

Replace all existing content with new content.

```
new FileWriter(file);
```

Keep the existing content and **append** the new content in the end of the file.

```
new FileWriter(file,true);
```

Example:

```
    FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

To append the stuff at the end of the file, use the [`append()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method of `FileWriter`

Answer (score 1):

change the FileWrite liner to:

```
output = new FileWriter(password_file, true);
```

which tells FileWriter to append

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you type

```
new BufferedWriter(output);
```

or "write", you are overwriting the "output" file.  Try to make sure you only declare a new BufferedWriter once throughout the course of the program, and append() to the file instead of write().