# How to insert the data into the file in java? No Append

Tags: java, file, io

I have to use the file as the database , But I am confused that how to insert the data into file . It is very stupid that copy the file and add the new data then rewrite a new file. And I notice that many database have store the data into the file and they both write in C/C++ . And I wonder how to achieve same function in Java. But I had try many times , use RandomAccessFile and FileChannel to insert the data . But it just overwrite the data at the position i want to insert .Some inspire idea will be help!
Thanks :)!

Here is code I had ever write.But it overwrite ! overwrite!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Reader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new File("a.txt").createNewFile();
        FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("a.txt"),StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        buf.put("one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n".getBytes());
        buf.flip();
        fc.write(buf);
        //set the pos to insert the data
        //I want to insert the data after three the pos is 14
        fc.position(14);
        //clear the buf and add the new data
        buf.clear();
        buf.put("five\n".getBytes());
        buf.flip();
        fc.write(buf);
        fc.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614227/how-to-add-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: I want to insert the data in any line in the file .No just at the tail. Thanks XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to "insert" a line in the middle of a file.  Filesystems and I/O subsystems don't work that way.  To truly insert a line you have to copy the file and add the line in the right place as you are copying.

You say *"...many database have store the data into the file ..."* -- this is true, but they do it with sophisticated block-level techniques where they maintain chains of blocks on disk and update pointers to make it look like the rows are inserted.  A lot of work goes into making all this transparent to the database user.

Writing even a simple "database" that can insert data in the middle of a file is a significant amount of work.

Comment: I will try another way to achieve the same funciton. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *insert* in the middle of a file. C/C++ cannot do that either.

To insert in the middle of a file, the rest of the file content has to be moved, to make room for the new data.

*You* have to do such a move. There is no built-in API for that, not even in C/C++.

The data files of a database are complex, and even they don't insert new data in the *middle* of a file.

Comment: Does their data maintain by a B-tree? It is really hard to me to use the B-tree to maintain the data in the file... XC

Comment: The data files of a database are ***COMPLEX***. It is way out of scope to cover that here, especially considering that every database does it differently.