# Insert line by line data in txt file with arraylist

Tags: java, file, arraylist

My program is about contacts.
When a Doctor for an example insert name,surname,telephone, everytime he wants to save the data into txt file then output will be:

```
somename
somesurname
sometelephone

somename
somesurname
sometelephone
...
```

Right now i did the output will be only in one line:
`somename somesurname sometelephone` as you can see at the code:

```
if(text.equals("Save")) {               
    try {       
        ArrayList<String> contactsinformations=new ArrayList<>();
        String name=tname.getText();
        String surname=tsurname.getText();
        String telephone=ttelephone.getText();
        contactsinformations.add(0,name+" ");
        contactsinformations.add(1,surname+" ");
        contactsinformations.add(2,telephone+" ");  

        FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("Contacts.txt");
        BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(outFile);                   
        for(int i=0; i<contactsinformations.size(); i++)
            outStream.write(String.valueOf(contactsinformations.get(i)));                
        outStream.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data saved.");  

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR IN FILE");
    }
}
```

I use for loop to get the size of the ArrayList but trying to figure out how can I insert the informations in different line.

**WARNING: UPDATED QUESTION!**
Question solved with just a true!

```
if(text.equals("Save")) {               
                try
                {       

                    ArrayList<String> contactsinformations=new ArrayList<>();               
                    contactsinformations.add(tname.getText());
                    contactsinformations.add(tsurname.getText());
                    contactsinformations.add(ttelephone.getText());                 
                    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("Contacts.txt",true);
                    BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(outFile);                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < contactsinformations.size(); i++) {
                        outStream.write(contactsinformations.get(i));   
                        outStream.newLine();
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data saved.");  
                    outStream.close();
                 }
```

Comment: `contactsinformations` is `ArrayList<String>` so its `get` method already returns String. What is the point of wrapping it with `String.valueOf`?

Comment: BTW each time you call `new FileWriter("Contacts.txt")` it clear content of used file. If you want to append text to already existing file without clearing it take a look at [How to add a new line of text to an existing file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4614227)

Comment: You can also wrap `BufferedWriter` with `PrintWriter` which has `println` method. For example `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Contacts.txt", true)));`

Comment: @Pshemo no need of BufferedWriter between `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Contacts.txt"));` is valid

Comment: @azro True, if we don't need buffering provided by BufferedWriter. From what I see ins [source code of PrintWriter](https://zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/io/printwriter.java) it adds `BufferedWriter` automatically only while handling `OutputStream`, or `File file`, or `String file`, but not when handling other `Writer` (although for that case buffering may still be provided by other means which I didn't notice).

Comment: It works but  there is no another way of use BufferedWriter?

Comment: Forget what i said. Guys it works! just use FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("Contacts.txt",true); Questin has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
outStream.write(contactsinformations.get(i) + "\n");
```

Here `\n` signifies the new line.

Comment: @TedHopp : I couldn't find the `writeln()` of `BufferedWriter`, is it on a higher java version? I'm on java-8.

Comment: Yes. You said \n signifies the new line. I use \n but the output is the first letter of the name

Comment: No its just empty

Comment: Use a debugger to see if the correct values are being assigned to the list. Adding a new line after that is a piece of cake.

Comment: he output is letter null letter by line

Comment: Oh so that means the new line works fine. Now  the issue is that the right values aren't getting set to your array list. You need to trace out the reason behind that by, indeed, more debugging :-)

Comment: I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. As `ArrayList` preserves insertion order you don't need to precise the `index` and you can omit the *useless* variables `name, surname, telephone` **:**

   ```
   contactsinformations.add(tname.getText());
   contactsinformations.add(tsurname.getText());
   contactsinformations.add(ttelephone.getText());
   ```
2. As the type of the `ArrayList` is `String` you don't need the `valueOf` method **:**

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < contactsinformations.size(); i++) {
       outStream.write(contactsinformations.get(i));
       outStream.newLine();
   }
   ```
3. The `PrintWriter` class has a method to do both in one call (combine with for-each loop here) **:**

   ```
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outFile);
   for (String contactsinformation : contactsinformations) {
       pw.println(contactsinformation);
   }
   ```

Comment: Better to use `outStream.newLine()` rather than writing a hard-coded `"\n"`.

Comment: You mean by the first to use it as result this way: ArrayList<String> contactsinformations=new ArrayList<>();    
     contactsinformations.add(tname.getText()+" ");
     contactsinformations.add(tsurname.getText()+" ");
     contactsinformations.add(ttelephone.getText()+" ");

Comment: @RubenOchoaPerez I've edit, no need of +" " as it's at the end of the line

Comment: When i use the method 3 i get null

Answer (score 0):

```
outStream.write(contactsinformations.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
```

Comment: Please add some details description, so that anyone can understand your answer at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `CharArray` and the write `BufferedWriter` :

```
for(int i=0; i< contactsinformations.size(); i++) {
    String str = contactsinformations.get(i) + "\n";
    outStream.write(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length()); 
}
```

or write the String by using offset and length the same way as above:

```
for(int i=0; i< contactsinformations.size(); i++) {
    String str = contactsinformations.get(i) + "\n";
    outStream.write(str, 0, str.length()); 
}
```

Comment: Please think about it before posting your answer, look at the other one if you don't think to all by yourself : valufOf is 100% useless and what it's the gain of write the method instead of the classic with String only ?

Comment: If your comment was only about `String.valueOf()` you are 100% correct. I edited.