# how to write newfile if the file name not exist and append file?

Tags: java, file, createfile

I have question about how to create file and append it.

what i have is 
`String getDate = "2020-04-02"` for name file. 
so my file will create every day if the date different one so my format for save file is

2020-04-02.text and for tomorrow my data will save in 2020-04-03.

after that my input data is

```
String savefile ="aaaa|bbbb|2020-04-02T08:18:35.146"
```

my question is how to create file and append my data to fix save file ?

i have try using

```
      System.out.println("savelocation: " + paths);
      Files.write(Paths.get(paths), savefile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
              StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

but i got error like this

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ec2-user/saveFile/EUR/USD|2020-04-02.txt
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
```

my expected code is :
1. Check file path it is exist or not if it is exist append data 
2. if file path it is not exist create new file and write new data

regards

Fuad

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about your question visit below URL.
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_create.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_read.asp

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

Writer output;
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(my_file_name,true));
output.append("New Line!");
output.close();
```

It is from below URL.

[How to add a new line of text to an existing file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614227/how-to-add-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: hi i want to writeln file.... how to writeln and append it using java ?

Comment: import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

Writer output;
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(my_file_name,true));
output.append("New Line!");
output.close();

It is from below URL.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614227/how-to-add-a-new-line-of-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

I hope it helps you.

Comment: yes your code is for append but how to create new file before have the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.time.LocalDate` class to create the filename. If you want to append data if the file exists then you can send second parameter to the `FileWriter` object as `true` It opens the file in appending mode.

You can check file exists or not using a method `exists()` in `File` class.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String savefile ="aaaa|bbbb|" + java.time.LocalDateTime.now().toString();

        String fileName = java.time.LocalDate.now().toString() + ".txt"; 

        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()){
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
            fw.write("\n");
            fw.write(savefile);
            fw.close();
        } else{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
            fw.write(savefile);
            fw.close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: oh i see but for append how to create new line in that file @Raju Komati

Comment: you can add new line using `fw.write("\n")` then you can append data using `fw.write(data)` method.

Comment: hi @Raju Komati i have update my expected code my expected code is : 1. Check file path it is exist or not if it is exist append data 2. if file path it is not exist create new file and write new data

Answer (score 0):

hi all thanks for all of you this problem done... with this code

```
 System.out.println("savelocation: " + paths);
  Files.write(Paths.get(paths), savefile.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
          StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

thanks for all of you... i miss the function about path in linux